How to receive payments for selling app subscription on Google Play in a country that does not support merchant registration?
Question for colleagues from Georgia, Kyrgyzstan, Greenland, and other countries who publish their apps in Googlе Play - these countries are not on Google's list of countries where you can sell subscriptions to apps. How do app developers get around this ban? I've met some fragmentary information that you can connect third-party payment systems like paypal, payoneer, wise and bypass this restriction, but there is no more information. Please share your experience, is it really impossible to bypass this restriction and developers are limited only by the income from advertising?
did a search on stackoverflow, reddit, and a few other sites. found some relative answers, but I believe they are outdated
I want to either confirm this problem, or get a refutation from people who have overcome this limitation and successfully received payments from Google

Not a complete answer but there used to be a page in the google play documentation mentionning that you are allowed to use third-party payment providers within the app, in the case GPP was not available, not they seems to have removed this policy or I cannot find the documentation anymore.
So the actual answer for now is : you can integrate a third party provider on your website as of now as long as you do not link or mention it directly within the app.
So in your app, you would just say "This ... needs a subscription" don't add any link, button or anything, and it's up to the user to figure out they need to go to the website to subscribe. Very AH move from google but that's as far as we can get for now.

thank you.
Decided to register a sole entrepreneurship in a nearby country where there are no such limitations

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
